# Topic data format in Kafka for KSQL operations

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I just started using ksql, when I do print topic from beginning I get data in below format.

```
   rowtime: 4/12/20, 9:00:05 AM MDT, key: {"messageId":null}, value: {"WHS":[{"Character Set":"UTF-8","action":"finished","Update-Date-Time":"2020-04-11 09:00:02:25","Number":0,"Abbr":"","Name":"","Name2":"","Country-Code":"","Addr-1":"","Addr-2":"","Addr-3":"","Addr-4":"","City":"","State":""}]}
```

But all the examples in KSQL have the data in below format

```
{"ROWTIME":1537436551210,"ROWKEY":"3375","rating_id":3375,"user_id":2,"stars":3,"route_id":6972,"rating_time":1537436551210,"channel":"web","message":"airport refurb looks great, will fly outta here more!"}
```

so I'm not able to perform any operations, the format is showing as

```
Key format: JSON or SESSION(KAFKA_STRING) or HOPPING(KAFKA_STRING) or TUMBLING(KAFKA_STRING) or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
```

on my topic. How can I modify the data into the specific format?

Thanks

Comment: I tried to create stream with Value_format as Avro but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

ksqlDB does not yet support JSON message keys, (See the tracking [Github issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4461)).

However, you can still access the data, both in the key and the value.  The JSON key is just a string after all!

The value, when reformatted, looks like this:

```
{
  "WHS":[
    {
      "Character Set":"UTF-8",
      "action":"finished",
      "Update-Date-Time":"2020-04-11 09:00:02:25",
      "Number":0,
      "Abbr":"",
      "Name":"",
      "Name2":"", 
      "Country-Code":"",
      "Addr-1":"",
      "Addr-2":"",
      "Addr-3":"",
      "Addr-4":"",
      "City":"",
      "State":""
    }
  ]
}
```

Which, assuming all rows share a common format, ksqlDB can easily handle.

To import your stream you should be able to run something like this:

```sql
-- assuming v0.9 of Kafka
create stream stuff 
  (
    ROWKEY STRING KEY,
    WHS ARRAY<
      STRUCT<
        `Character Set` STRING,
        action STRING,
        `Update-Date-Time` STRING,
        Number STRING,
        ... etc
      >
    >
   )
   WITH (kafka_topic='?', value_format='JSON');
```

The value column `WHS` is an array of structs, (where the will be only one element), and the struct defines all the fields you need to access.  Note, some field names needed quoting as they contained invalid characters, e.g. spaces and dashes.